# Compiling 32-bit Qt application using 64-bit package

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, qt-creator, 32bit-64bit

I'm using Windows 8 64-bit, Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 64-bit and Visual Studio 2012.

I have no trouble compiling and running my application on 64-bit OS, but apparently it doesn't work on 32-bit OS. Is there a way to compile 32-bit application with what I have, or should I install Qt for Windows 32-bit? (I download Qt from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads).)

If it's possible, I would like a hint at where that option is. I'm using Qt Creator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible with 64bit library, but you can download and install the appropriate "Qt 5.0.2 for Windows **32**-bit" (you can configure targets in Creator to have multiple versions of Qt installed)