# How do you change kits in Qt to target an x86 machine?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm currently working on a project in QtCreator. I'm using a library that is x86 based but my current project is targeting an x64 architecture. The obvious solution is to change my project to target an x86 architecture. However, I have no idea how to do this.

I've gone into the appropriate window to configure a new Qt kit. This kit uses the MVCC x86 compiler. I then select this as my default project. After running the new qmake, I attempt to build the project yet get the same error regarding using a 32 bit library in a 64 bit project.

So my question: how do I apply a new kit in Qt? I assume I should be able to click the 'Open Build and Run Kit Selector'and select the kit, however, this just gives me the options of select the x64 kits.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: Under Project button on sidebar select the correct kit in the little black window where you select build/run mode. Click the name of the kit that looks like a title of the black box (I think Desktop is default) and select your kit. I think it's also possible to make default kit under tools->options->Build&Run->Kits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First make sure the kit is added in the Build & Run menu of the Options panel. I think you have performed this step already:

[image: Add kit to Build & Run menu]

Then go to the Projects tab after you have loaded your project and click on "Add Kit". There you should be able to select your newly added kit:

[image: Add kit to project]

Finally, you should then be able to select it from the kit selector:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, When I attempt to add the kit after selecting the Build & Run tab, my kit shows up but it is grayed out. I go back to my kit and notice that I haven't select a Qt version. When I select my Qt version (5.7 64 bit), it states that I can't use it to target x86. So do I need a 32 bit version of Qt to target to x86 projects?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. This is also confirmed by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729126/compiling-32-bit-qt-application-using-64-bit-package).

Comment: Okay I will do that. Also, this may be a really stupid question, but what exactly does 'Qt version' all include? Referring to this webpage on Qt versions (http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html), it states that you can have multiple Qt versions to target multiple platforms. However, what does Qt version entail? When I think of Qt, I think of all the components (Qt creator, Qt designer, Qmake, etc.). By having different Qt versions, what is different?

Comment: The individual components of Qt, e.g. Qt Core, Qt Gui, Qt OpenGl, Qt Quick, Qt etc. Qt Creator (which includes Qt Designer IIRC) and QMake carry their own versions numbers, which are distinct from the "Qt version".

Comment: So what does "Qt version" entail then? Is it just referring to the program that processes/transforms your Qt project before sending it off to the C++ compiler?

Comment: I think I just realized what you are talking about. A Qt version is really just a particular installation of Qt. E.g. "Qt 5.6.0 MinGW 32-bit" or "Qt 5.6.0. MSVC 2015 64-bit". It is the toolchain Qt is built with (and to be used with) and the release version.